# Making dynamically added p elements clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make the elements clickable. However on clicking any of the `<p>` elements there is no alert box saying "hello". Please could you look at my code and possibly point me in the right direction?

```
function createLink(text, parentElement) {
  var a = document.createElement('p');
  var linkText = document.createTextNode(text);
  a.appendChild(linkText);
  a.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("hello");
  };
  parentElement.appendChild(a);
  var br = document.createElement('br');
  parentElement.appendChild(br);
}
var txtFile8 = new XMLHttpRequest();
txtFile8.open("GET", "http://www.drakedesign.co.uk/mdmarketing/uploads/date.txt", true);
txtFile8.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (txtFile8.readyState === 4) { // Makes sure the document is ready to parse.
    if ((txtFile8.status == 200) || (txtFile8.status == 0)) { // Makes sure it's found the file.
      allText8 = txtFile8.responseText;
      arrayOfLines8 = allText8.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
      for (i = 0; i < arrayOfLines8.length - 1; i++) {
        createLink(arrayOfLines8[i], document.getElementById("previousResultsList"));
      }
    }
  }
};

txtFile8.send(null);
```

The script parses a text file online:
http://www.drakedesign.co.uk/mdmarketing/uploads/date.txt

Which is updated weekly and has dates written in it like so:

19/04/16

12/04/16
...

My script separates the text document into each line and stores it as an array. A for loop is then used to show the dates on the screen in a column which looks like so:
[image]

The problem is that on clicking each date an alert box is not shown saying "hello" and there seems to be no response at all.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Open your console and check for errors.

Comment: remove the `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Stop using Internet Explorer^^ Only browser-specific testing is ok

Comment: Working here https://jsfiddle.net/hdkrvwxd/

Comment: If you test it in IE older then version 9 or if IE is in compatibility mode, then `preventDefault()` does not exist and an error will be thrown.  But the only way to figure out what the problem might be is that you check the error message in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue!!

The problem was that I had divs with opacity 0 that were overlaying my parentElement! sorry stupid mistake!